# iOS IAP Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 in Production

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am seeing quite a few failed in-app purchases with the error description reading `Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=<some hex value> {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}`.

What causes this?  Every answer I've found on SO is several years old and says this error relates to sandbox issues or trying to buy an IAP in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

According to my own experience this error (Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2) comes when a user cancels the In-App-Purchase in the system confirmation dialog. So this is not an error, per se. The cancelation is falsely reported as error, would be of cause better if StoreKit reported it as a cancelation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. There's a thread on the Apple dev forums discussing the problem [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8439). An Apple staff member was working to track the issue at one point. It seems to be a bug introduced in iOS 8.4. I was hoping for a fix in iOS 8.4.1 but the problem seems to persist.